# All stills added to iMovie are blurry during playback

Tags: imovie

I am desperately trying to finish this iMovie video for someone and I am having difficulty with the playback of my still images.  They look great/normal when scrolling through the storyboard, but as soon as I press play the images blur.  I am using iMovie 10.0.5 on a MacBook Pro from 2009.  Any help would be beyond greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: The original resolution or size of the picture should be as good or better than that of the video. If you have the picture in Finder command+I to see info regarding size and dpi.

Comment: If you can afford it my advice is to get FCP X for $20 off Ebay.  iMovie has been glitchy for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried exporting your video? Sometimes iMovie downscales things while playing it back in the application.

If that doesn't work try copy and pasting your project timeline into a new project and re-insert the images you have.